# Multiple laravel connection with mysql

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to do two Laravel connections with two databases in MySQL.In my  database.php file I have added mysql2 connection.

```
 <?php

 return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| PDO Fetch Style
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
| stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
| array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
|
*/

'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Database Connection Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
| to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
| you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
|
*/

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database Connections
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
| Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
| supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
|
|
| All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
| so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
| choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
|
*/

'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],


    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'db1'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password1'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],


    'mysql2' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '3306',
        'database' => 'db2',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'password2',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],





    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
    ],

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migration Repository Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
| your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
| the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
|
*/

'migrations' => 'migrations',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Redis Databases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
| provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
| such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
|
*/

'redis' => [

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],

];
```

And in my routes file I added this route

```
Route::get('/', function()
{

$users =DB::connection('mysql2')->select('select * from users')->get();

return $users;

});
```

But when I browse to get the result of the query

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 729:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.users' doesn't exist
```

I need someone helps me .

Comment: Laravel version?

Comment: laravel  version 5

Comment: Can you show the whole database.php file?

Comment: you should say full version :) Laravel connection has changed a lot from 5.2->5.3->5.4

Comment: Are you sure the User and Password on mysql2 are right?

Comment: yes am sure............

Comment: do you have the user table in mysql2? from the error seems like you app is trying to access "test.users" whereas at mysql2 you set db2.

Comment: yes please see my answer

Comment: Please accept your answer for your question so that noone else wastes their time here if your problem is resolved.

Comment: I couldn't accept it now of course according to the system of stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

```
//use model
$user = new \App\User();
$user->setConnection('mysql2');
$users = $user->all();
return $users;
```

Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 0):

The default env() of database.php file direct to the .env file, so can't find table. Remove the env(), just like upper.

Comment: By occasion  could I make two MySQL connections in .env file?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my function on routes.php to the following and the problem solved
(get function deleted).

```
Route::get('/', function()
{

    $users =DB::connection('mysql2')->select('select * from users');

    return $users;

});
```